How to duplicate and mirror particle hair on asymmetrical model?
Please tell me, how to duplicate hair on asymmetrical model in particle system & mirror it to the other side?
I made a hairstyle on one side of the head & I want this finished part to appear on the other side of the head, but neither Shift+D nor Ctrl+V work. Also, model is asymmetrical & therefore it wasn't possible to make hair on both sides at once. Model already has weights & is ready for animation, so duplicating the mesh itself & mirror it together with half the hairstyle is not an option.


For symmetrical objects, the hair particles can be mirrored with the menu entry Particle > Mirror. The hair must be selected.  - If the object is asymmetrical this doesn't work but you could convert the particles to hair curves and mirror them with a Geometry Nodes modifier. Then convert them back to hair particles or work with the new hair curves. By the way, can't you make a symmetrical hair cap and use this as an emitter?

Can you please give more details on how to do this?
And regarding hair cap, I simply duplicated part of mesh from finished head with ready weights & therefore it's not symmetrical.

For symmetrical objects, the hair particles can be mirrored with the menu entry Particle > Mirror. The hair must be selected.
This does not work if the object is asymmetrical. But there is a solution:

convert the particles to hair curves. Blender will create a Curves object named Particle System.


then mirror them

in Blender 4.2, you can do this simply in Edit mode. Press Shift+D,Esc to duplicate them. You can use the 3D Cursor (.) as pivot point and mirror the curves by scaling them with factor -1 along the X-axis (SX-1).
in Blender 3.6, the duplicating the curve points in Edit mode does not work. But a Geometry Nodes modifier can do the same for you. Add and apply the modifier to make the changes permanent.



finally, convert the curves back to hair particles (or work with the new hair curves if you don't need Hair Dynamics)

enter the Surface object, usually the hair cap or the head and the UV map in the Curves settings.
switch to Sculpt mode, and use the menu to snap the curves to the surface.
finally, use the menu again to convert them back to a Particle System





Thanks!It works, but not perfect.Firstly, hairstyle changes a little in places where hair didn't fit head.Also need to remove all hair settings before converting, otherwise won't be able to even reduce amount of hair to animate.But if remove all these, hairstyle changes a little again.This can be corrected, although pity it don't remain original.But main problem is that when converting to curves there are too many dots appearing & when returning to particles it becomes inconvenient to edit, and it also slows down hair animation a lot.Is it possible to somehow reduce the number of these points?

oh yes, I forgot about the particle settings. They will be lost and you will have to enter them again at the end. It's also a good idea to turn off Children before you convert the particles so only the parent hair particles get converted. -- The number of points can be reduced by a Geometry Nodes modifier that has a single Resample Curve node in it. The Count setting defines the number of control points.

It works! The number of dots on curves has decreased. Thank you very much for your help!
